# Classes within java

Tags: java, loops, class, methods

So I took everyone's feedback and information and have spent quite a bit of time trying to work on my code prior to submitting.  Here are the changes that I have:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

class Automobiles {
    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    int mileage;
    int i;
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }

    public void setMileage(int mileage) {
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

public Automobiles() {
    make = "";
    model = "";
    color = "";
    year = 0;
    mileage = 0;    
    }

    public void Inventory(String make, String model, String color, int year, int mileage) {
        System.out.println("Car is: " + make + " " + model + " " + color + " " + year + " " + mileage);
    }

        String getMake() {
        return make;
    }


}

public class AutomobileInventory {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Automobiles[] carInventory = new Automobiles[15];
        int i;
        String fileName = "out.txt";
        boolean quit = false;
        String quit1 = "No";

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (quit1 != "Yes") {
        for(i=0; i<carInventory.length; i++) {
            carInventory[i] = new Automobiles();
            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println("Please Enter the make of the vehicle: ");
            carInventory[i].make = scnr.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please Enter the model of the vehicle: ");
            carInventory[i].model = scnr.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please Enter the vehicle color: ");
            carInventory[i].color = scnr.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please Enter the year of the vehicle: ");
            carInventory[i].year = scnr.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Please Enter the vehicle's mileage: ");
            carInventory[i].mileage = scnr.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Are you done? Yes or No");
            quit1 = scnr.nextLine();

            }
        } 

        for(i=0; i<carInventory.length; i++)
        System.out.println(carInventory[i].make + " " + carInventory[i].model + " " + carInventory[i].color + " " + carInventory[i].year + " " + carInventory[i].mileage);

         try {
            PrintWriter outputstream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
            outputstream.println(carInventory[i].make + " " + carInventory[i].model + " " + carInventory[i].color + " " + carInventory[i].year + " " + carInventory[i].mileage);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am running into an issue now that as it completes the loop the first and second instance are combining and it is not allowing me to enter a string for Make each time.  Also when I printed to a file it only printed one instance and not all of the instances.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to initialize quit variable.

Comment: Actually, you havn't initialized `automobiles` either.  There are two `autmobileInventory` methods, and you are not calling using the one that initializes `automobiles`.   Please review the difference between static and instance methods and how Java decides which to call.

Comment: Your code has many different issues.  I strongly suggest you stop and go back through some basic Java tutorials to learn how to declare classes and instantiate objects of those classes.

Comment: Thank you I have made a few changes after doing the best that I could to go back through my notes and making sure I spent some more time with objects and classes.  Any other help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because you aren't initializing the *quit* variable, and are using a do-while loop, the loop executes once without checking if *quit* = "quit". This causes the loop to appear to execute fine, but then crash on the second iteration.

If we examine the structure of how the loop executes:

1) Print "Car Model:"
2) Print "Car Make:" 
3) Print "Car Color:"
4) Print "Car Year:" 
5) Print "Car Mileage:"
6) Execute For loop
**7) Evaluate whether quit == "quit"**
8) Print "Car Model"
9) Etc...

When step #7 attempts to evaluate the equality, it is actually performing this comparison:

```
!null.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));
```

Because above in the code, the variable *quit* was never initialized, and is still set to null. The two code snippets below are in essence equivalent:

```
// Initialization without assignment:
String quit;

// Explicit initialization to null:
String quitTwo = null;

// Output
print quit
// >> NullPointerException

print quitTwo
// >> NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

As @kushagra mentioned, you need to initialize your quit variable. It's currently null, hence the NullPointerException (trying to call a method that doesn't yet exist for your variable)

One tip regarding your quit variable though, I would change it to type boolean since all you need is a true/false. This way, you don't have to do any string comparisons. It would look something like this:

```
boolean quit = false;
...

do { /* loop stuff */ }
while(quit != true);
```

Then in your do loop, you can add logic to change your quit variable to true when your user is ready to quit.

Regarding your inventory, I wouldn't use an array if you don't have to; I would use a list (arrays can't change size, whereas lists can). Then instead of using your for loop (you're already looping with your do-while - makes it a little redundant), you can add a new automobile to your list where you currently have it commented out. It would look something like this:

```
private static List<Automobile> automobiles;
...

automobiles.add(new Automobile(make, model, Color, year, mileage));
```

**UPDATE**

Your code is pretty messy - make sure you're consistent with your tabbing/spacing/etc. You should also come up with a clean way of organizing your methods. For example, I like to keep all my getters and setters together with constructors right below the class properties. The bottom of the class is where I like to keep general class methods, overridden methods, etc.

One issue you have with your code is in your main(...); try not to loop within loops if you don't have to (obviously there are always exceptions, such as multidimensional arrays, traversing "grids", etc) - this can slow down execution quite a bit (check out Big O notation - this is a pretty good article: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/). This will also help you keep track of when your loop closes.
Your file write only happens once because you're not looping (this is where consistent indentation/spacing may help you).

Couple more quick tips: whenever you reuse a value, make a variable for it. You did this a few times, but there were several instances where you could have used a variable (remember: method calls take time to run, so limiting redundant calls will speed up your program). Also, don't be afraid to override the toString() method in your classes - the automobiles class is actually a really good use case for it.

I tried not to give you all the answers, but I've rewritten your code a bit to help you get going:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


class Automobiles {
    String color = "";
    String make = "";
    String mileage = "";
    String model = "";
    String year = "";


    // -------------------- getters -------------------- //
    public String getColor() { return color; }
    public String getMake() { return make; }
    public String getModel() { return model; }
    public String getMileage() { return mileage; }
    public String getYear() { return year; }


    // -------------------- setters -------------------- //
    public void setColor(String color) { this.color = color; }
    public void setMake(String make) { this.make = make; }
    public void setMileage(String mileage) { this.mileage = mileage; }
    public void setModel(String model) { this.model = model; }
    public void setYear(String year) { this.year = year; }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return year + " " + model + " " + make;
    }// end toString()
}// end class Automobiles


public class AutomobileInventory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Automobiles> carInventory = new ArrayList<>();
        String fileName = "out.txt";
        boolean quit = false;

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            Automobiles car = new Automobiles();

            System.out.println("Please Enter the year of the vehicle: ");
            car.setYear(scnr.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Please Enter the make of the vehicle: ");
            car.setMake(scnr.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Please Enter the model of the vehicle: ");
            car.setModel(scnr.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Please Enter the vehicle color: ");
            car.setColor(scnr.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Please Enter the vehicle's mileage: ");
            car.setMileage(scnr.nextLine());

            carInventory.add(car);

            System.out.println("Are you done? Yes or No");
            quit = "yes".equals(scnr.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase()) ? true : false;
        } while(quit == false);// end do-while-loop

        int numCars = carInventory.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < numCars; i++) {
            String currentCar = carInventory.get(i).toString();
            System.out.println(currentCar);

            try {
                PrintWriter outputstream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
                outputstream.println(currentCar);
            } catch( FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }// end try-catch
        }// end for-loop
    }// end main(String[] args)
}// end class AutomobileInventory
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Automobile` class is fine.

---

In your `automobileInventory` class, your are initializing static data member in a non-static method (Check the function where you are initializing the `automobiles` array).

You can simply initialize it where you are declaring it i.e.:

```
private static Automobile[] automobiles = new Automobile[ INVENTORY_SIZE ];
```

Another way is to initialize it in a `static` block i.e.:

```
private static Automobile[] automobiles;

static {
    automobiles = new Automobile[ INVENTORY_SIZE ];
}
```

Another way is to initialize it in your function before your loop.

---

In your sentinel-controlled loop, you are checking exit condition on `quit` variable but you are not assigning it anything. You need to get value from user whether he/she intends to quit or not.

Here's an example:

```
String quit; // In your function; not a class member

do {

   // ... Rest of your code ...

    System.out.println("Do you want to quit [Yes/No]? ");
    quit = scnr.nextLine();
}
while ( !quit.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") );
```

---

And, you need to take care of your array instance of `automobiles` that it is correctly being populated. You need to take care of its index that it remains valid.

```
String quit; // In your function; not a class member

int i = 0;

do {

   // ... Rest of your code ...

    if ( i < INVENTORY_SIZE ) {
        automobiles[i] = new Automobile(make, model, color, year, mileage);
        i++;
    }
    else {
        // ... Display error message here that array is full ...
        // ... You can then break this loop to exit if you want to ...
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("Do you want to quit [Yes/No]? ");
    quit = scnr.nextLine();
}
while ( !quit.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") );
```

---

Here's your working code: https://ideone.com/JqX9Y9

Some of the lines are commented for my own testing. You can easily correlate the changes with this answer and figure out yourself what is going on.

---

Best of luck!
Happy coding!